# Transpose rows to single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQLServer. I have a query which gives the following result.

```
1 Apple
1 Banana
1 Orange
```

Is there anyway in SQL to traspose it to the following:

```
1 Apple Banana Orange
```

Comment: Post your sql statement please so we can at least tell how you are doing this and provide better help.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the big picture?

Comment: Please specify the *version* of SQL Server also.

Comment: And also specify whether `Apple Orange Banana` is ONE column or THREE.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT id, names = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + name
    FROM dbo.[table] WHERE id = t.id
    FOR XML PATH(''), 
        TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.[table] AS t
-- WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I've used this in the past and it works well, but it is slow.

Comment: @Jerry are you sure you perceived actual slowness, or did you rely on what an estimated plan might have told you? I'm doing some significant testing and while the estimated plan for inlining this XML shows very high costs, the *actual* costs (CPU, duration, reads) end up being very, very low. What methods have you used that are faster *in practice*?

Comment: The issues I've had may very well be the environment in which SQL Server is running.  But, in my experience, using STUFF() and FOR XML PATH() together is a relatively slow operation.  I don't have exact numbers to share, but I have a fairly complex query I run here on a regular basis with 4 or 5 of them in it and it takes 1 to 2 seconds to run with them in and a small fraction of a second with them out.

Comment: @Jerry can you be more explicit? By "with them out" do you mean without FOR XML and without STUFF, or without STUFF? If you're not using FOR XML, how are you performing the concatenation? The STUFF is just a nicety to strip out the leading comma (or other concatenation character), which could just as easily be done in the front end. In this case I'm still not even clear whether it's a pivot or a concatenation that's desired.

Comment: Sorry, in the case I was mentioning, I was referring to removing the entire STUFF(SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()) subqueries from the main query.  In other words, it seemed that the overwhelming majority of the time spent in the query was running the subqueries using that construct.  I'm no DBA, but I play one at my company, so it is entirely possible that other things were combining with it to cause the slowdowns.  But, I've consistently had significantly slower queries when using the above as a subquery within a main query.

Comment: Right, but I'm still trying to coax out of you what specific method you used *instead* of STUFF & FOR XML that was faster in your case. If you say a solution is slow, ok, but help people out by explaining what wasn't as slow.

Comment: I didn't find a better way, only noting that using it made the query significantly slower than it was without it.  I was not, in any way, attempting to criticize your solution with my original comment.  In effect, I was trying to say "this is a great solution, but it comes at a price".  Sorry for the confusion and the need for so many exchanges to get to the point.

Comment: @Jerry OK, but to be clear I think the problem with speed has to do with the intention of the solution, not the method. In most cases I usually encourage folks to handle this concatenation at the presentation layer, since there really isn't a super-efficient way to do this in T-SQL other than denormalizing (and nobody wants that). So for lack of being able to provide a super-efficient solution, I lean toward elegant, unless the target is SQL Server 2000, where it has to be a *really* slow UDF.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which DBMS, so I'm assuming Oracle:

```
SELECT id, LISTAGG(name, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY id;
```

or

```
SELECT id, wm_concat(name)
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL SERVER 2005 you can use xml, something like this

```
SELECT
  [Name] + ' ' as [text()] 
FROM fruits 
ORDER BY [Name] 
FOR XML path('')

for example

WITH fruits ([No],[Name]) AS (
SELECT
    1 , 'Apple1'  
UNION SELECT
    1, 'Banana1'
UNION SELECT
    1, 'Orange1'

UNION SELECT
    2, 'Apple2'
UNION SELECT
    2, 'Banana2'
UNION SELECT
    2, 'Orange2')

SELECT 
    [Name] + ' ' as [text()] 
FROM (SELECT [No], [Name] FROM fruits ) as fr 
ORDER BY [Name] 
FOR XML PATH('')

GO
```

Or if you like a more general example:

```
 WITH fruits ([No],[Name]) AS (
SELECT
    1 , 'Apple1'  
UNION SELECT
    1, 'Banana1'
UNION SELECT
    1, 'Orange1'

UNION SELECT
    2, 'Apple2'
UNION SELECT
    2, 'Banana2'
UNION SELECT
    2, 'Orange2')

SELECT 
    ft.[No], 
    (select [Name] + ' ' as [text()] from (SELECT [No], [Name] FROM fruits ) as fr where fr.[No] = ft.[No] ORDER BY [Name] for xml path('') ) as [Names]
 FROM 
    fruits ft
 GROUP BY [No]
```

Note: Remember to drop the last space in `[Names]`

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL for known values of *fruit*

```
with T(id, fruity) as (
   select 1, 'Apple'  union
   select 1, 'Banana' union
   select 1, 'Orange' union
   select 2, 'Apple'  union
   select 2, 'Banana' union
   select 3, 'Orange' 
)
SELECT * FROM T
PIVOT (
    MAX(fruity) 
    FOR fruity in ([Apple],[Banana],[Orange])
) pv

>>

id  Apple   Banana  Orange
1   Apple   Banana  Orange
2   Apple   Banana  NULL
3   NULL    NULL    Orange
```